# Embedding Openfire

Tags: eclipse, embed, shutdown, openfire

Is it possible to embed an Openfire server (version 3.7.0) in a Java application?

I am trying to run integration tests on the server in Eclipse.  However, because Openfire is in Standalone Mode (the condition for this being that it can find its ServerStarter bootstrap class), when the server tries to shutdown, it calls System.exit(0) which I do not want to happen.

Is there any way to stop this from happening, i.e. without just deliberately preventing Openfire from finding its bootstrap class?

Answer (score 3):

I have a successful approach, which is fairly straightforward and much easier than trying to manually set up Openfire.

Install Openfire onto a machine(Mac, PC, etc), setup with the admin console using the embedded database, and then comment out the adminConsole from openfire.xml if you'd like.

Copy the directory to a location you want to run your unit tests from.  If you want to ensure exact repeatability, then it would be wise to zip and unzip the directory every time you run the tests.

Ensure all the all the jars(openfire, hsqldb, mail, bouncycastle, jasper, etc) are added.

Now you should be able to start and stop normally.  Openfire does have one quirk.  Because it's singleton oriented, even if you shutdown, that singleton instance stays around, so if you want to use it in something like a unit test, you'll have to call XMPPServer.getInstance() to check if an instance already exists, then call the constructor if getInstance() returns null.

I hope that helps.